# MP4 not played in IE10

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, video, mp4

I am using in my .aspx file the following code:

```
<video controls="controls" >
    <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="movie.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
    <source src="movie.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

in web.config I placed:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  ...
```

In FF22 the mp4 movie is displayed in the correct way, but in IE10 I get the error 'Invalid source'. If I create a basic HTML file with the same 'video' tag, I can view the video also in IE10 (with file: protocol). For some reason the filetype in IE10 for the MP4 file is always 'application/octet-stream', instead of 'video/mp4' as specified in the web.config.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: i m also facing the same issue, could you please tell here, how did you get it resolved.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Has anybody figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

sApparently you can't override this in a location tag or even in your web.config like so:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension="ogg"/>
  <remove fileExtension="mp4"/>
  <remove fileExtension="webm"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension="ogg" mimeType="video/ogg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension="webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension="mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
</staticContent>
```

Instead, I had to add .mp4 under mime types in the GUI (this doesn't appear to have altered web.config at all) as a local definition:

[image: mp4 mime type in iis GUI]

Confirmed with fiddler, the .mp4 is now served with a content type of video/mp4 (even though the staticContent tag was defined previously)